# Javascript print div not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have a Javascript function that prints the contents of two  elements in a webpage. It works in Chrome, Firefox and IE but Safari just brings up an empty window and if I select print, it simply prints a blank page.

Here's my code:

```
var content = "<!doctype html><html><head>";
content += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalise.css" type="text/css" />';
content += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/App_Themes/CS2011/StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />';
content += "</head><body>";


//Find the div to insert the rest of the html after
var contractToFind = $(divElement).parent().find("div").get(0);

//Insert rest of code
content += contractToFind.innerHTML;
content += "</body></html>";

//Set up print window and print
var printWindow = window.open('', '', params);   
printWindow.document.write(content);
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.focus();
printWindow.print();

//Close the window
printWindow.close();
```

Is there a way I can modify my code to allow it to render the page properly in Safari so I can print it? Preferably without using additional plugins.

Edit: Thanks Eric but that didn't work for me. Adding a time delay to the print seems to work well although it's not ideal, even a 10ms delay solves the issue. The line I used was:

```
setTimeout(this.print, 100);
```

Comment: In general I have the idea that its better to avoid `document.write()`.  Is it an option to do `printWindow.document.body.innerHTML = content`? I have to add that I dont have much experience with popup windows.

Comment: Whats the final solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. The problem resides in the fact that `window.print()` is not standard for all browser and Safari probably takes a different approach on when triggering it.

I changed a little your code so maybe this solution can't fit your possibility but it works for all browser (tested on Safari, FF, Chrome, IE8).

*Note that you need to have a different page for the popup content (I changed the code to retrieve the contract to make a sample for myself, hope you will figure out how to get contract content).*

### The code:

**HTML for the page that opens the popup**

```
<body>
    <input type="button" id="popup" value="Open Popup" />
    <div id="yourContract">
        <div>blablabla</div>
        <div>blablabla2</div>
        <div>blablabla3</div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>blablabla td1</td>
                <td>blablabla td2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>blablabla td3</td>
                <td>blablabla td4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $("#popup").click(function(){
        var win = window.open("static.html");
    });
</script>
```

**HTML for the popup (static.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.holdReady(true);
            $.getScript("print.js", function() {
                $.holdReady(false);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var contract = window.opener.$("#yourContract").html(); //change to fit your needs
            $("body").html(contract);
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**JS file (print.js) called by static.html**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.print();
    window.close();
});
```

### How does it works:

`static.html` consists of two `script` section. The section in the body loads via javascript the content in the page.

The section in the head prevent the document to trigger `ready` status by setting `holdReady` to `true`. Then it loads `print.js` which waits for document to be ready, but we will decide the exact moment because we are preventing it.

After  the script is included in the page `holdReady` is set again to false, triggering the `ready` status to document and calling the `print()` and `close()` functions on the `window`.

This however occurs after the browser has loaded all the page content, so you will see the preview in the popup page and the print dialog.

Hope this solution is what you need.